# column doesn't exists exception when trying to sum in sqlite query in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQlite database to store data.. but when I try to sum the columns using query I am getting error `Column doesn't exists` like below:

```
select _id, column1, sum(column2),sum(column3) from table
```

At the same time when I write without sum I am able to see the result in application as below.

```
select _id, column1, column2,column3 from table
```

Column2 and Column3 are `Real` data type columns.

I have no clue about this behaviour, why it is behaving this way.

Code to retrieve the columns from cursor.

```
summaryviewholder.Total.setText(String.valueOf(getsummary.getInt(getsummary.getColumnIndexOrThrow(st.column2))));
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187): Process: com.example.portfoliomanager, PID: 8187
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'Buy_Qua' does not exist
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at com.example.StockDirector.stockmanager$popsummarystock.bindView(stockmanager.java:518)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at com.example.StockDirector.stockmanager$popsummarystock.newView(stockmanager.java:539)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2720)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2214)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1351)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1235)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6476)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-25 15:53:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(8187):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 15:53:25.486: I/Process(8187): Sending signal. PID: 8187 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `getsummary.getColumnIndexOrThrow(st.column4)` ... Where is `column4` defined? Mind to show your `DBHelper` class?

Comment: @DerGolem I apologize its column2 not column 4.. updated my question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Mind to show your `DBHelper` class? Because it doesn't find the column `Buy_Qua`. I suspect that the table is not being created due to a misspelling in the **CREATE TABLE** command.

Comment: @DerGolem I have created a table class.. apologize I can't show all columns in public forum but pasted till `Buy_Qua`. I will call this table class in `dbhelper class` to create tables and any other classes where required

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you, if I don't see the **real**, **complete** CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `SELECT sum(Column2)`, then the name of the output column is `sum(Column2)`.

You should either read the column values by their index (which is dangerous when the query ever changes), or give the output column another name:

```
SELECT sum(Column2) AS Column2Sum ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response in this case with what name should I retrive the column from cursor.. I mean with column name or alias name?

Comment: The alias name becomes the column name.

Comment: As per your sugestion I have changed in this case I got different error.. please sugges. I gave alais name as `a`. Updated my question thanks

Comment: The problem in your question has been solved. To search help for a *different* problem, ask a new question.

Comment: It was not the new problem.. problem of the asked question and thanks for your answer.. I was able to solve the issue using your answer and also a bit of googling

Answer (score 2):

You have to name your rows you summarize.

Other notes:

If you use `sum` (or aggregation function in general), you can't select other rows that are not aggregated, or else you won't get a proper result.
Also, use `Float` for getting the value from the database, as you use the `Real` datatype (floating point number) in sqlite.

So instead of this:

```
select _id, column1, sum(column2),sum(column3) from table
```

You have to do something like this:

```
select column1, sum(column2) AS sum1, sum(column3) AS sum2 from table group by column1;
```

And to the values:

```
summaryviewholder.Total.setText(String.valueOf(getsummary.getFloat(getsummary.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sum1"))));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response when I try in the way you suggested it is giving error like `_id` doesn't exist

Comment: You can't get the _id if you summarize like this. The results are not for the single rows but for group of column1 which have no unique id. I updated my answer to address another problem.

Comment: I have tried according your suggestion but getting error 'Column _id' doesn't exist

Comment: Remove the _id from the select and don't use it here. You can't select it if you do summarizing.

Comment: I don't know why but your approach is not working always getting error `Column _id` doesn't exits..Thanks for your assistance.